# Cartier Divisor can have torsion element?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I was reading Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry*, and I realize that Cartier divisor can have torsion elements, but I can't find such an example.

I know for the Noetherian scheme that is locally factorial, the Cartier divisor is isomorphic to Weil Divisor and we know Weil Divisor group is free therefore it's torsion-free. So this can only happen when the Weil Divisor do not isomorphic to Cartier divisor is there any example that the Cartier divisor has a torsion element.

Comment: 'We know that Weil divisor group is free' - no, that is incorrect

Comment: @Cranium Clamp , I use the definition on Görtz and Wedhorn in page 309 Weil divisor group is free Abelian group $Z^1(X) = \Bbb{Z}^{(X^1)}$ where $X^1$ is set of integral clsoed subscheme of codimension 1, therefore it's free?

Comment: I don't know if that's what you're calling the Weil divisor group, but I was talking about that modulo the principal divisors.

Comment: Ok thank you @Cranium Clamp , no matter what convention you adopt,  does the group $Div(X) = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}^\times_X / \mathcal{O}^\times_X)$
 has torsion element?

Comment: I copy one sentence from Lazarsfeld's page 44: let the $\Bbb{Q}$-Cartier $D = cA$ for some $A$ be integral divisor then "$cA = 0$ iff $A$ is torsion element of $Div(X)$." it seems that $Div(X)$ has torsion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ U $ be the complement in $ \mathbb{P}^2 $ of a smooth curve $ C $ of degree $ d $. There is the standard exact sequence of Weil divisor groups / divisor class groups (just to be clear, I'm quotienting out by principal divisors, call it whatever you want to)

$$ \operatorname{Cl}(C) \rightarrow \operatorname{Cl}(\mathbb{P}^2) \rightarrow \operatorname{Cl}(U) \rightarrow 0 $$

It's well known that $ \operatorname{Cl}(\mathbb{P}^2) $ is $ \mathbb{Z} . H $ where $ H $ is the class of a hyperplane, and the image of the first map is obviously $ dH $ so $ \operatorname{Cl}(U) \cong \mathbb{Z} / d\mathbb{Z} $ is torsion whenever $ d > 1 $.

EDIT: I managed to confuse myself horribly, late at night. yi li's original question seems to be this - does $ \Gamma(X, K_X^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_X^{\times} ) $ have torsion elements? If $ X $ is the cuspidal cubic defined by $ y^2 - x^3 $ and we consider the global section $ y/x \in \Gamma(X, K_X^{\times}/ \mathcal{O}_X^{\times} ) $ then $ (y/x)^3 = y \in \mathcal{O}_X^{\times} $ showing that torsion may exist. EDIT2: Of course, this is wrong. I'm going to leave it here for now and come back when I'm awake.

Comment: Thank you for the example, Is it possible that $Div(X) = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}^\times_X / \mathcal{O}^\times_X)
$ has torsion

Comment: In the answer, every variety is smooth so the divisor class group coincides with the group of Cartier divisors that you write.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but there is no quotient $Div(X) = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}^\times_X / \mathcal{O}^\times_X)
$ here? The example only shows $Div(X)/PDiv(X)$ may have torsion?

Comment: Ok, if that's your question, then the answer is no for any variety where the notion of Weil coincides with Cartier, for instance, locally factorial and regular in codimension one. So indeed, as you say, you need a variety where these notions do not coincide. Sorry for being sloppy.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure but the statement in Lazarsfeld's  book seems to incline that there exist some variety that $Div(X) = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}^\times_X / \mathcal{O}^\times_X)
$ has torsion, may be some uninteresting pathological case

Comment: yes, but that example doesn't work as the singularity is normal. That's about it. Hopefully my answer now is correct.

Comment: Yeah thank you for your help Cranium Clamp

Comment: @yili I edited the answer after writing that comment. But I realize that's also wrong...

Comment: Wow that is a very interesting example, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146005/discussion-between-cranium-clamp-and-yi-li).